# Problem with \printchessgame parameters

Tags: xskak

\printchessgame takes the parameters **initmoveid** and  **stopmoveid**.
If I enter the ids directly anything works fine.
However, if I set **stopmoveid=\xskakgetgame{lastmoveid}** I get an error.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[german, ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{xskak}

\begin{document}        
    \newchessgame[id=demo]

    \hidemoves{%
    1.d4 Nf6 
    2.c4 g6 
    3.Nc3 Bg7 
    4. Nd5 d6 
    }

% Works well
\printchessgame[initmoveid=2w, stopmoveid=4b]

\typeout{Last move id = \xskakgetgame{lastmoveid}}

% Replace 4b by \xskakgetgame{lastmoveid} generates error
\printchessgame[initmoveid=2w, stopmoveid=\xskakgetgame{lastmoveid}]

\end{document}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: This is a bug. Contact the package author ;-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a strategically placed `\expandafter`

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[german, ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{xskak}

\begin{document}        
    \newchessgame[id=demo]

    \hidemoves{%
    1.d4 Nf6 
    2.c4 g6 
    3.Nc3 Bg7 
    4. Nd5 d6 
    }

% Works well
\printchessgame[initmoveid=2w, stopmoveid=4b]

\typeout{Last move id = \xskakgetgame{lastmoveid}}

% Replace 4b by \xskakgetgame{lastmoveid} generates error
\printchessgame[initmoveid=2w, stopmoveid\expandafter=\xskakgetgame{lastmoveid}]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is only a workaround. It is better to correct the package code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer And that would be your domain, as the author, if I recall.  Me?  I grasped at straws and managed to hold on to one.